# Bad file name or number

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am getting error

> "Run time error '35': Bad file name or number"

when i use this code to open a text file that is accociated with my app.

File association is set up using inno.

when i replace `Command$` with `"C:\Users\Dave\Documents\jconv.cppl"` and run it in design mode there is no error.

Code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim DoubleClickedFile As String
    Dim sFileText As String
    Dim iFileNo As Integer

    DoubleClickedFile = Command$

    If DoubleClickedFile <> "" Then

        DoubleClickedFile = Mid(DoubleClickedFile, 4, Len(DoubleClickedFile) - 3)

        Text1.Text = DoubleClickedFile 'to check if the file and path is good

        iFileNo = FreeFile
        Open DoubleClickedFile For Input As #iFileNo
        Input #iFileNo, sFileText
        Text1.Text = sFileText
        Close #iFileNo

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What has this question got to do with VB.NET?  That looks like VBA code.  Please apply the correct tags to your question so that people who can help you are likely to see the question and you won't waste the time of those who can't help.

Comment: That said, if the code you have doesn't work and replacing `Command$` with a hard-coded path does, `Command$` must not contain that same path.  Have you actually looked to see what it does contain, because you haven't indicated so to us?

Comment: What is the value of DoubleClickedFile before the Open statement?